# socket.gethostbyname doesn't behave well

Tags: python, sockets, gethostbyname

I'm using `gethostbyname` function for DNS and IP addresses checking. However, it does not work well in this case:

```
>>> from socket import gethostbyname
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
'67.215.65.132'
>>> gethostbyname('lns.sa')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>>>
```

It gives two diffrent answers, once belonge to OpenDNS and the other is `Name or service not known`, the right one. After a couple of seconds, it works fine. Could someone explain this behavior and is `gethostbyname` reliable to be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `gethostbyname()` at all - the domain `lns.sa` really doesn't exist.

The address `67.215.65.132` is the one provided by OpenDNS for domains that don't exist.  It's name is `hit-nxdomain.opendns.com.`

Most likely you have one OpenDNS server configured, and one from someone else.  OpenDNS are re-writing any "not found" domains, the other provider isn't.